# googlemap API JS not draggable on IOS only

Tags: javascript, ios, google-maps, draggable, touchscreen

I have created a .js script that generates googleMap on a website

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
    zoom: 17,
    center: {lat: -21.0407089, lng: 55.2682027}
  });
```

When using my created maps on PC, MAC or Android terminal, I can manipulate my maps as i wish, dragging and zooming.

but on ISO (I tried to use Safari, chrome or Opera) the map is displayed, but is not draggable by touching the creen. I can zoom, but only by using the buttons displayed at the bottom at the page, not with fingers.

I tried to add draggabkle: true in mys js script, but it does not change anything.

As I said, this dragging problem only occurs on IOS

Thanks for your help

Martin

Comment: Can you post your code in where you implement the draggble=true. Try to get some example [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/), then check if the drag event here does not work in IOS for you to verify that that draggable properties doesn't work on IOS.

Comment: It looks like somebody has already reported this in the public issue tracker:    https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10515